# How do you fix a massive `.git` folder (2Gb+)?

Tags: git, git-lfs

The project I'm working on involves some large files (eg. Jupyter notebooks, some data files, some pickled objects) - and over time the .git folder has become very large.

Right now it's at 2.1Gb, but the trajectory is clear and not good.

What options do we have? I'm aware of:

1. Archive the git history and copy over the HEAD to a fresh repository (and be more careful with large files).
2. Prune large files from the history.
3. Implement something like git-lfs going forward.

Any recommendations?

Comment: This feels like you're looking for a discussion, which is not really what SO is well-suited for. Which path is correct for you depends on what *your* priorities and constraints are. The first two look like a temporary fixes unless you also change your process to not include big files in git in the future. Only the third (or the fourth: fix your process to not put big files in git) is a viable long-term solution.

Comment: Well, what's the source of the heft - is it files you _currently_ have in the repo or files that were added accidentally and deleted? Or something else? For a long-lived repo that's not actually that big, I have several that are multiple GBs, for example.

Comment: It's mainly the Jupyter notebooks. These files include images and some big data files, which makes them a few MB in size.